# Daily status using prior value as backfill

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

This is the input table (tbl_statuslog):

| User_id | isactive | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 Feb 2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 Feb 2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 Feb 2021 |
| 2 | 0 | 5 Feb 2021 |
| 4 | 1 | 10 Feb 2021 |
| 4 | 0 | 10 Feb 2021 |
| 3 | 0 | 12 Feb 2021 |

```sql
create table tbl_statuslog
(
  [user_id] int,
  [isactive] bit,
  [date] datetime
);

insert into tbl_statuslog (user_id, isactive, date) values
(1, 1, ' 1 Feb 2021'),
(2, 1, ' 1 Feb 2021'),
(3, 1, ' 2 Feb 2021'),
(2, 0, ' 5 Feb 2021'),
(4, 1, '10 Feb 2021'),
(4, 0, '10 Feb 2021'),
(3, 0, '12 Feb 2021');
```

I want to return output, given today is 16 Feb:

| User_id | isactive | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 Feb 2021 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 16 Feb 2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 Feb 2021 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 4 Feb 2021 |
| 2 | 0 | 5 Feb 2021 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 2 | 0 | 16 Feb 2021 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 Feb 2021 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 3 | 1 | 11 Feb 2021 |
| 3 | 0 | 12 Feb 2021 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 3 | 0 | 16 Feb 2021 |
| 4 | 0 | 10 Feb 2021 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 4 | 0 | 16 Feb 2021 |

I have used following SQL to get the list of all dates.

```sql
    DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME
    
    SET @StartDateTime = '2021-02-01'
    SET @EndDateTime = GETDATE();
    
    WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
    (
        SELECT @StartDateTime as Date
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData)
        FROM DateRange 
        WHERE DateData < @EndDateTime
    )
    SELECT DateData
    FROM DateRange
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
    GO
```

Now I am thinking of doing a left join of this table with `tbl_statuslog` table. Thus I have a date irrespective of whether date exists in `tbl_statuslog` or not.

Then I want to backfill the `isactive` value for the date and `user_id` based on the previous value.

Can I use window function- example `partition by user_id, order by date` to achieve the result?

I'm blocked here because when evaluating the `isactive` value for a date and `userid`, how can I get access to prior 1 day value, or value of 2 days prior (and so on) when the previous day doesn't have value?

Comment: If you add your sample data as DDL+DML it makes it much easier for people to assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

I would suggest using recursion but only for each row:

```
with ts as (
      select ts.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by user_id order by date) as next_date
      from tbl_statuslog ts
     ),
     cte as (
      select user_id, date, isactive,
             coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, next_date), convert(date, getdate())) as end_date
      from ts
      union all
      select user_id, dateadd(day, 1, date), isactive, end_date
      from cte
      where date < end_date
     )
select user_id, date,  isactive
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2fa716a9d08dbf563770ccc9de03ae79) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: In ts you are getting the next date into the current row. Can you tell me what is happening in the subsequent sql cte

Comment: @variable . . . It keeps adding one more day to the date until it hits the last date.

Comment: Will this work when the date column is of type datetime?

Comment: @variable . . . It should, assuming there is no time component.

Comment: How to go about in case of a datetime column? For example in case of user id 4.

Comment: @variable . . . It is better to ask a *new* question rather than invalidating answers by editing a question that already has answers.

Comment: Ok appreciate the help. I have made a new question for datetime field here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247153/daily-status-using-prior-value-as-backfill-datetime

Comment: In case of user_id 4, on same date There are 2 values on is_active. How is this answer handling this scenario?

Comment: @variable . . . This fills in the dates between each row in the original data.  The `isactive` flag is comes from the first row, so it is just "inherited" on the following rows.  No problem.